# hoverOn and hoverOff is not working - if statement - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Starting from line 75 on, I'm trying to make in if statement to add all the span elements by returning them but it's giving me an error.

It is expecting a ",", and am not sure what to add. Wrap the whole element span in strings?

https://github.com/cjl85/bloc-jams-react/blob/master/src/components/Album.js

Line 84 is what is giving me the error. The return statement should be expecting that string with a comma.

```
      {this.state.album.songs.map((song, index) =>
    <tr className="song"
      key={index}
        onClick={() => this.handleSongClick(song)}
          onMouseEnter={() => this.hoverOn(song)}
            onMouseLeave = {() => this.hoverOff(song)}>
    <td>
    if{(this.state.hoverOn === song)} {
          {return <span className = "ion-md-play"></span>)};
    }}
    // {(this.state.hoverOn === song) ? (<span className="ion-md-play"></span>) :
    //  (this.state.isPlaying === true && this.state.currentSong === song) ? (<span className="ion-md-pause"></span>) :
    //  (this.state.isPlaying !== true && this.state.currentSong === song) ? (<span className="ion-md-play"></span>) : null }
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write like this

```
const { isHovered, isPlaying, currentSong } = this.state
return(
 /* Code Before */
 {isHovered === song ? (<span className="ion-md-play"/>) : null}
 {(isPlaying === true && currentSong === song) ? (<span className="ion-md-pause"/>) : null }
 {(isPlaying !== true && currentSong === song) ? (<span className="ion-md-play"/>) : null }
)
```

could you check again ?

But i saw on your code where is isHovered in state it's func so could you check it

Comment: no it's not working, it keeps erroring as fatal error, expecting a curly bracket